# Add elements to Array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list of array list:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> NodesAndServices = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();
```

I want to add eachRow of `NodesAndServices` to another arraylist `allChars`:

```
    List<Character> allChars = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < NodesAndServices.size(); i++) {
    List<Character> eachListRow = NodesAndServices.get(i);

    for (List<Character> chr : eachListRow) { //Error
        for (char ch : chr) {
            allChars.add(ch);
        }
    }
}
```

But u get compile time error:

```
required: java.util.list
found: java.lang.character
```

**UPDATE**

```
for (int i = 0; i < NodesAndServices.size(); i++) {
    List<Character> eachListRow = NodesAndServices.get(i);

    for (Character chr : eachListRow.get(i)) { //Error,foreach not applicable to type character

            allChars.add(each);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not related to the question, but `NodesAndServices` should start with a lowercase to meet Java conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (List<Character> chr : eachListRow) { //Error
```

When writing an enhanced `for` loop like this one, the loop variable `chr` will take the value of each element of the collection `eachListRow`, which is a `List<Character>`. Therefore, `chr` must be of type `Character`, not `List<Character>`.

Then you'll realize you don't even need the nested loop:

```
for (Character chr : eachListRow) { // OK
    allChars.add(ch);
}
```

---

Note: you could also use an enhanced `for` loop for the first loop, leading to the following code, which is much nicer to read:

```
List<Character> allChars = new ArrayList<Character>();

for (List<Character> eachListRow : NodesAndServices) {
    for (Character chr : eachListRow) {
        allChars.add(ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`eachListRow` is not a list of lists. Try this:

```
 for (Character chr : eachListRow) {...
```

**Update:**

```
 for (int i = 0; i < nodesAndServices.size(); i++) {
        List<Character> eachListRow = nodesAndServices.get(i);

        for (Character chr : eachListRow) {
            allChars.add(chr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get this error: `foreach not applicable to type character `

Comment: @S-H, remove this error line, it's redundant because you already got the character in `chr`. Just add `chr` to you result list.